# Issue with pycharm remote debug with script parameters ("env: No match." )

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, pycharm, remote-debugging

When I execute a script in pycharm remote without any arguments it runs fine.
However, once I add arguments (script parameters), I get `env: No match.`  error while executing a debug session

My arguments looks like

```
--arg1=value1 --arg2=value2
```

I tried setting it without `'='` and get the same error

Here is the full command showed on the debugger window:

```
ssh://null@localhost:2213/home/gamir/yuval/anaconda2/envs/tf_011b/bin/python -u /specific/a/home/cc/cs/yuvval/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 45437 --file /home/gamir/yuval/remote_py/nlteach/show_attend_and_tell/evaluation_wrapper.py --checkpoint_path=/home/gamir/yuval/nlteach/output/train/d=cub/imSD=11%imSP=rnd%tcSP=cvpr16/VSat --cnn_model=resnet_v1_50 --eval_dir=/home/gamir/yuval/nlteach/output/eval/d=cub/imSD=11%imSP=rnd%tcSP=cvpr16/VSat --input_file_list=/home/gamir/yuval/data/CUB_TF/d=cub/imSD=11%imSP=rnd%tcSP=cvpr16/learn.img_val.ids --image_set=img_val --images_split_seed=11 --teaching_split_type=cvpr16 --teaching_split_seed= --output_data_dir=/home/gamir/yuval/data/CUB_TF/ --images_split_type=rnd --dataset_raw_dir=/home/gamir/yuval/data/CUB_TF/raw/ --teach_set=learn --dataset_name=cub --num_examples_per_epoch=3125 --early_stop_metric=Perplexity/min --early_stop_patience=6 --multi_params_checkpoint_dir_depth=2 --input_file_pattern=/home/gamir/yuval/data/CUB_TF/d=cub/imSD=11%imSP=rnd%tcSP=cvpr16/TFRecords/learn.img_val-*.tfrecord --early_stop_min_epochs=3 --eval_interval_secs=1 --multi_params_evaluation_loop=True --gpu_memory_fraction=0.31
```

and without arguments (successful)

```
ssh://null@localhost:2213/home/gamir/yuval/anaconda2/envs/tf_011b/bin/python -u /specific/a/home/cc/cs/yuvval/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 44571 --file /home/gamir/yuval/remote_py/nlteach/show_attend_and_tell/evaluation_wrapper.py
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue. The remote interpreter didn't like the fact that I had the symbol `*` on one of the arguments. I fixed it by escaping with a backslash `\*` instead of `*`